# SDK Manager doesn't pop after launch on Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, eclipse-plugin

SDK Manager doesn't pop as I click on the button to load it.
It shows that it's loading but nothing happens. 
Can anyone give me some tips to solve it? This is my path on System Variables:

path : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin; C:\Users\MyPC\android-sdks\tools; C:\Users\MyPC\android-sdks\platform-tools

I tried to uninstall and install the plugins again, but no wizard window pops up even after I restart Eclipse.

Comment: Eclipse hasn't been supported for Android development for more than 4 years now.

Comment: So there is no reason to develop for Android on Eclipse? This is a only Android Studio business?

Comment: Android Studo is the only thing supported by Google

Comment: So to develop Android, Android Studio it's the most recommended IDE? Isn't there any chance to do it on Eclipse?